# Questions on Google AdWords Data

Tags: google-ads-api

Regarding Google AdWords:

1. Does their data contain details of the person/user who is
   generating the clicks/impressions?  Such as employer, organization?
2. Is there a way to see the geography of clicks/impressions?

Thank you!
Ashish

Answer (score 0):

1. No, they're pretty closed on user-level data. You can only access aggregated clicks/impression
2. Yes, it's possible to segment by geo-location through the API and in the interface